# "Nous voilà donc accros au pourpier" -- Where's the verb ?

Tags: grammaire

This sentence was in [a podcast](https://onethinginafrenchday.podbean.com/e/le-pourpier/) I listen to, at the 2:15 mark of the most recent episode "Le Pourpier." I checked the transcript to confirm I had heard it right.

I'm quite confused by it-- I would have thought this would need to be "Nous *sommes* voilà donc accros au pourpier"....why does this sentence not need a verb? It seems to read (approximately) "So, we addicted to purslane!"

Comment: I'd translate it to "Here we are, addicted to purslane" which then includes the verb. There are many cases where no verb is valid "En route pour de nouvelles aventures" is often used and would translate  to "On our way towards new adventures" which also has no verb but again "we are on our way to new adventures" would be implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point besoin du verbe pour faire des phrases. Une réponse certes un peu concise, mais une réponse tout de même, pour un phrasé rendu de plus amplement acceptable par la présence étymologique d'un verbe. Et [vois-là](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voil%C3%A0) !

Comment: Vous semblez indiquer qu'un _phrasé_ qui ne contient pas même indirectement l'étymon d'un verbe serait acceptable. Mais est/serait-ce une phrase a part entière ? Autrement qu'est-ce formellement ? Une locution, un groupe quelconque ? Merci !